# Rails: Accessing the username/password used for HTTP Basic Auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-authentication

I'm building a basic API where user information can be retrieved after that user's login and password are correctly sent.

Right now I'm using something like this:

`http://foo:bar@example.com/api/user.xml`

So, what I need to do is access the user/password sent in the request (the `foo` and `bar`) but am not sure how to access that info in a Rails controller.

Then I'd check those variables via a quick `User.find` and then set those as the username and password variables for `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic`.

It's possible I'm looking at this at the completely wrong way, but that's where I'm at right now. :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The answer to your question of how to get the credentials from the request is this:

```
user, pass = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::user_name_and_password(request)
```

However authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic is all you need to do basic auth:

```
class BlahController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  protected

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      # you probably want to guard against a wrong username, and encrypt the
      # password but this is the idea.
      User.find_by_name(username).password == password
    end
  end
end
```

authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic will return a 401 status if credentials are not supplied, which will pop up the username/password dialog in a browser. If details are given then those are passed to the block provided. If the block returns true the request goes through. Otherwise the request processing is aborted and a 403 status is returned to the client.

You can also check out Railscast 82 (thats were the code above is from):
http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication

Comment: This is a really helpful answer - something that seems simple reading about it but I was wondering how to do this.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

The rails plugin [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) supports this functionality (as well as much more) out of the box.  You could root around in the source for it, or simply integrate it into your existing application.

**Edit:**
After digging around the source code for Authlogic, I found [this file](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb) which uses the following piece of code to grab the username and password:

```
  def authenticate_with_http_basic(&block)
    @auth = Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(controller.request.env)
    if @auth.provided? and @auth.basic?
      block.call(*@auth.credentials)
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

I'd look a bit further into where it all goes, but I've got to get to bed.  Hope I was of some help.