# Authentication login issue RESTful iOS

Tags: ios, rest, ios5, authentication, afnetworking

Hey Folks i have a problem with authentication for the login credentials of my app. I currently have a rails web service running from my localhost, that features a main login screen for a admin user with password credentials to display functions.

The problem is that i am creating a RESTful iOS application running alongside my rails app, that just takes these JSON requests and bypasses them.

All i want is to create a way for me to enter admin and password without having to use auth_token? it seems to be the only way to do it, to simply authenticate the admin user first in the keychain. Im using the framework AFNetowrking for authentication.SSKeychain a wrapper for accounts, and SVProgressHUD for lightweight huds

.I also have the JSON and XML requests being logged in the i terminal but failing due to not being able to connect to the server with this error

```
error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo=0x7556d50 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:3000.json/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:3000.json/, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSUnderlyingError=0xeb805c0 "Could not connect to the server."}
```

this is how im storing the credentials for the authClient, all want to do is specify the same info used to log-into the web service client which is.

username:admin and password:taliesin

but unsure how to do this?

these are what i have so for the AuthAPIClient, CredentialsStore and LoginViewController

**update** if anybody knows a easier way to do this please can you let me know, will be much appreciated.

**AuthAPIClient.m**

```
#import "AuthAPIClient.h"
#import "CredentialStore.h"

#define BASE_URL @"http://admin:taliesin@localhost:3000"


@implementation AuthAPIClient

+ (id)sharedClient {

static AuthAPIClient *__instance;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL];
    __instance = [[AuthAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseUrl];
});
return __instance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
if (self) {
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self setAuthTokenHeader];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(tokenChanged:)
                                                 name:@"token-changed"
                                               object:nil];
}
return self;
}

- (void)setAuthTokenHeader {
CredentialStore *store = [[CredentialStore alloc] init];
NSString *authToken = [store authToken];
[self setDefaultHeader:@"auth_token" value:authToken];
}

- (void)tokenChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
[self setAuthTokenHeader];
}

@end
```

**CredentialStore.m**

```
#import "CredentialStore.h"
#import "SSKeychain.h"

#define SERVICE_NAME @"http://admin:taliesin@localhost:3000"
#define AUTH_TOKEN_KEY @"auth_token"

  @implementation CredentialStore


- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
NSString *user = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%s%@", 'a', "a", @"a"];
NSString *password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%s%@", 'a', "a", @"a"];

NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user
                                                         password:password
                                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
[[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

}

- (BOOL)isLoggedIn {
return [self authToken] != nil;
}

   - (void)clearSavedCredentials {
[self setAuthToken:nil];
}

    - (NSString *)authToken {
    return [self secureValueForKey:AUTH_TOKEN_KEY];
    }

    - (void)setAuthToken:(NSString *)authToken {
[self setSecureValue:authToken forKey:AUTH_TOKEN_KEY];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"token-changed" object:self];
}

    - (void)setSecureValue:(NSString *)value forKey:(NSString *)key {
    if (value) {
    [SSKeychain setPassword:@"taliesin"
                 forService:SERVICE_NAME
                    account:key];
    } else {
    [SSKeychain deletePasswordForService:SERVICE_NAME account:key];
    }
   }

    - (NSString *)secureValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
return [SSKeychain passwordForService:SERVICE_NAME account:key];
  }

@end
```

**LoginViewApi.m**

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "AuthAPIClient.h"
#import "CredentialStore.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"

@interface UIViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *userTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CredentialStore *credentialStore;
@end

@implementation LoginViewController

+ (void)presentModallyFromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                         initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
[viewController presentViewController:navController
                             animated:YES
                           completion:nil];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.credentialStore = [[CredentialStore alloc] init];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                       target:self
                                                                                            action:@selector(cancel:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
target:self
                                                                                action:@selector(login:)];

[self.userTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)login:(id)sender {
[SVProgressHUD show];

id params = @{
@"admin": self.userTextField.text,
@"taliesin": self.passwordTextField.text
};

[[AuthAPIClient sharedClient] postPath:@"/auth/login.json"
                            parameters:params
                               success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                                   NSString *authToken = [responseObject       objectForKey:@"auth_token"];
                                   [self.credentialStore setAuthToken:authToken];

                                   [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                                   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                               } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                   if (operation.response.statusCode == 500) {
                                       [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Something went  wrong!"];
                                   } else {
                                       NSData *jsonData = [operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                       NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                                            options:0
                                                                                                 error:nil];
                                       NSString *errorMessage = [json objectForKey:@"error"];
                                       [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:errorMessage];
                                   }
                               }];

}

- (void)cancel:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Any help or for more questions please let me know cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

**Endpoint Addressing**

I don't know how `AFNetworking` handles remote addresses but I think you are making a simple mistake when calling `localhost` from `iOS` to contact your web-service. The thing is that `iOS` is an operating system and it has its own `localhost`. Thus, when you think you are calling a remote web-service you are actually asking `iOS` to look within itself for this service. Therefore, wether you are running your rails web-service locally or on an actual remote server, find out the IP address for the server where the service is running and use that as an  endpoint rather than `localhost`.

So update everything that points to your service to use an IP. Don't change it for `127.0.0.1`, that would have the same effect.

For example:

```
#define BASE_URL @"http://admin:taliesin@192.168.0.1:3000"
```

---

**Authentication:** `iOS`

Assuming your web-service supports, that is, you have configured basic http authentication; then authenticating from `iOS` should not be a huge problem.

If you were to use `RESTKit`, it would be as simple as:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
objectManager.client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic;
objectManager.client.username = username;
objectManager.client.password = password;
```

I use Apple's `KeychainItemWrapper` for storing/retrieving credentials on iOS.

```
//Store Account on Keychain (disk) for persistence.
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
KeychainItemWrapper *accountItem = appDelegate.accountItem;
[accountItem setObject:password forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
[accountItem setObject:username forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];   
username = password = nil; //keep account information only in the keychain.
```

I don't know if your code is correct but it should not be that complicated to handle `basic http auth`. Perhaps `AFNetworking` does not abstracts it as much as `RESTKit` does? Or perhaps you are not using the right methods from `AFNetworking` to do `basic http auth`? Basic auth does not require an access token and thus I suggest you read a little more about basic auth before implementing it.

---

**Authentication:** `Rails`

As for implementing authentication on `Rails`, it should not be too complicated either. All you need to do is to configure your controller to present an authentication challenge to the incoming request with `basic http auth`. One way to do this is by using `before_filter: authenticate`. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399467/rails-accessing-the-username-password-used-for-http-basic-auth).

I think Railscasts is superb and they happen to have a tutorial on [basic http auth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication) and one specifically for [rails 3.1. authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1).

Cheers.